# Search Button on Customized Gridview Takes Two Clicks to Fire Event

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a customized Grid control that is inherited from Gridview that has search and pagination. Everything works great except this one little thing. Whenever I use the pager to go to the next page, then I use the search, the event that handles the search does not fire on the first click, it takes a second click to get it to fire. Any ideas?

The code for the control is here:

[Grid.cs](https://sites.google.com/site/joecdevelopment/)

**Important Note**

I am aware that it is frowned upon to post large blocks of code... But, the entire control's code is posted to give the whole picture of how it is built. The control itself is a bit on the complex side as it performs searching, sorting, and pagination all server-side; and this code is a completely custom control that just INHERITS the GridView.

I AM NOT looking for someone to write a fix for me, just an idea of why this one situation may be happening!

With that said, to break things down a little more with the code... The search form (text box and buttons) are created dynamically and added in the CreateChildControls method. The search form works perfectly when the Grid is initially loaded, but after using the pagination, the first click of the Search button does not fire the method assigned to the Search button's command event, but the second click does. It seems as though something in the postback is not recognizing the button's command event has been triggered...

A trace of the calls to the methods show:

1st Click - Everything from ViewState is loaded, no postback events are called.

2nd Click - Everything from ViewState is loaded, postback events called.

I'm looking for ideas on where to go from here, as I've been trying everything I can think of page life-cycle wise to see if I can get this functioning properly. The only thing that has worked is setting EnableEventValidation to false on the page that implements the Grid control, and performing the "initial" data bind on every "Page_Load" (not just "if !IsPostback"). But, for obvious reasons, that is not an acceptable solution.

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: In the process of doing that now... It exceeds character limits, so it will be in chunks.

Comment: Please don't post too much code, only relevant parts. Nobody is going to look thru forest of lines

Comment: The entire control code is relevant as it shows how the control is built. Like I said, this is a custom control that inherits from GridView.

Comment: The community frowns upon pointing us to huge amounts of code, and asking for a fix for the problem.  See if you can create a minimal example that repeats the problem, and include that code here.  You should be able to narrow the issue down more than this.  See meta regarding the community's feelings on "code dumps" ([here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88842/discourage-code-dumps) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107058/how-do-you-prevent-here-code-you-fix-questions)).

Comment: Not asking for a fix, just ideas... Thanks for the input about "code dumps" though!

Comment: No worries, it appears you are new to posting here - so I wanted you to know where to go look for community consensus on things.  I removed my downvote, because I feel your question is a bit better after the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue... Posting here for anyone who might make a similar mistake.

In CreateChildControls(), I was executing the base before adding the search form to the control. A simple switch around to calling the base after adding the search form, and getting rid of the condition "if (this.HasControls())" resolved it. From what I can see, calling the base after adding any child controls allows those child controls to have their events/handlers properly registered.